# Вызов метода с исполнением всех действий

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить код. Так как точку входа нельзя поменять на public async void Main(string[] args). Приходиться создавать новый метод public async void main1(string[] args). Но как в этом методе выполнить все его действия

```
         public async void main1(string[] args)
    {
            MailRuManager MailRuManager = new MailRuManager();

            var userStat = await MailRuManager.SendRPC("goblins_startSession");
            Console.WriteLine(userStat.Result?.AttemptsCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
```

Comment: вызвать функцию в мейне?

Comment: Ну да что бы в Main выполнялись все действия те что в main1

Comment: Тут два варианта: 1. Это `static async void Run() { /*Логика*/ }` и уже в `Main` вызывать это просто как метод (`Run()`). 2. Сделать `public async Task Run() { /*Логика*/ }` и переписать консольный `Main` на что то по типу `static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. Но этот вариант многие не очень любят (хотя как по мне для консольного приложения самое то).

Comment: Просто используйте C# 7.1 или выше: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня и так последняя

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал как вы сказали и вообще в cmd все пусто

Comment: Это вы называете пустотой?) Хах. Будьте внимательный, пожалуйста! Не надо при каждой проблеме задавать вопрос! Посмотрите внимательней что вы выводите и что выводили.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так там же должна быть статистика //Отправляем запрос к RPC без параметров (метод goblins_startSession - получение статистики)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(userStat.Result?.AttemptsCount);` и `Console.WriteLine(userStat);` две одинаковые строки?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там просто выводит пустату. Когда у меня Console.WriteLine(userStat.Result?.AttemptsCount);

Comment: Это уже не относится к данному вопросу. Как вызвать подобные методы вам уже сказали (можете оформить ответом). Что касается пустоты, то это уже обратно к старому вашему вопросу, создавайте там чат и давайте разбираться... Смотря так, могу сказать, что `Result` сервер отдает вам `NULL`, а значит он выдает ошибку. Я даже работу с ошибками в отдельное свойство вам вывел (`userStat.Error?.Message`). Научитесь отладку производить приложения, иначе дальше вам не как...